# Linux Restricted Bash shell perform arithmetic calculations

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, restricted-shell

I have a shell script to calculate cpu and memory resources in a vm. For one task, I would like to perform mathematical calculations in a rbash shell. Could you please guide me the possible workarounds.

I have been trying like

```
echo $a / 1024 | bc
```

I'm trying the below substitution and getting the below error. Can you please advise me

Both the variables have decimal values as well. Like 0.4, 10.0 and would need to subtract and get the values

```
for used_cores in `echo (( $config_cpu - $free_cpu )) | grep [0-9] || echo NA`
do
echo $used_cores
done
```

Error:

```
bash: command substitution: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The question seems to be different from the reference question. Can you please consider this question.

Comment: Why do you think you need workarounds? What are you trying, and how is it failing?

Comment: `cd /` gives `rbash: cd: restricted` as I'd expect, but `echo $((44+66))` still correctly returns `110`. Also, if it's a script written to use (e.g.) `bash` then you should still be able to run it from `rbash` and have it use the shell's full unrestricted power

Comment: Actually I'm trying to add 2 variables and pipe the output to binary calculator.

Comment: I have been trying like # echo $a / 1024 | bc

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/685002/edit) to show a relevant (working) snippet or example of code. Don't put it in the comments - it can all too easily get missed

Comment: as said, please **edit** your question to explain more detailledly what the problem is; there's nothing special about restricted shells when it comes to arithmetics

Comment: @roaima your solution seems to be working in my case.  Thank you very much for your help and quick support.

Comment: or don't delete it, now that you've got answers, but instead accept roaima's answer

Comment: `(` is a special character to the shell: if you want to print it (or rather, pass it as an argument to some command as-is, here, to `echo`), you need to quote it. But if you want to do arithmetic, the syntax is `$(( 1 + 2 + 3 ))` etc., see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Arithmetic_Evaluation

Comment: Not that I'm exactly sure why you'd try to do some arithmetic, and then `grep` for a digit from the result. Any arithmetic result would contain at least one, and errors can be detected otherwise.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you for your solution. I will try and proceed. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

For an integer value of `$a` (you don't give an example value), the command `echo $a / 1024 | bc` should work perfectly under `rbash`. Even outside a script.

If you're using integer arithmetic (which seems to be the case as you haven't told `bc` otherwise) you may not even need to call out:

```
echo $(( a/1024 ))
```

"Works for me".

Comment: Im using IBM HMC CLI and the rbash. Unfortunately the rbash says "bash: bc: command not found"

Comment: Also I have been using a for loop like below. But I'm getting the below error can you please help me.

Comment: @satsensort seriously, **edit** your question!! This is all crucual information that a reader would have wanted before spending time on helping you!

Comment: for used_cores in `echo (( $config_cpu - $free_cpu )) | grep [0-9] || echo NA` ^do^ echo $used_cores^done

Comment: EDIT YOUR QUESTION !!!

Comment: @satsensort ... do you read the comments you get?

Comment: Error: Syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @roaima I think satsensort must be a bot, they don't react to language, maybe this is all scripted. Let's close this question. /s

Comment: I've VTC already. It's frustrating, because there are several of us trying to help this person but they won't help themselves

Comment: just did, too, yeah, this is a bit ridiculous.

Comment: I have edited the question sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 2):

It's a normal shell, so  the arithmetic operators do work:

```bsh
value=$(( a / 1024 ))
echo "$value"
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  Thank you for helping me..

Comment: Sorry in my case if i want to subtract 2 variables.  I'm getting the syntax error. Can you please guide on where I'm Missing